# Matching data frame columns based on multiple constraints in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, finance

I am working on a project with financial data. In this case I have two data frames, one containing fundamental values and the other with prices. Because I had to use two different databases the dfs differ in size, mainly due to mismatches in companies ('tic') and/or dates ('year').

Here is an example for fund_df:

```
        tic       assets      year
0      AAPL       123.99      1999
1      AAPL       143.20      2000
..     ...          ...       ...
200    GMCF         9.56      2013
201    GMCF        11.21      2014
..     ...          ...       ...
1543   TSLA       201.23     2015
1544   TSLA       233.49     2016
```

Whereas the prices_df looks like this:

```
        tic       prices      year
0      MPRD       56.789      2000
1      MPRD       48.222      2001
..     ...          ...       ...
200    GM         87.991      2012
201    GM        102.334      2013
..     ...          ...       ...
1543   ZZ         34.567      2017
1544   ZZ         29.887      2018
```

My goal is to unify these two dfs so that I can work with both fundamental and price values. However, because I am afraid that the datasets my differ both under a tic and year point of view, I wish to unify these values based on a match that needs to be at both levels, so that the fundamental values of TSLA in 2015 match the price of TSLA in 2015.

I have tried the following piece of code:

```
merged_df = merge(fund_df, prices_df, by.fund_df=['tic', 'year'], by.prices_df['tic', 'year'], all = TRUE)
```

However I keep on receiving this error message:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Can anyone help me find a solution to merge the two dfs based on both a tic and year constraint?

Thank you in advance for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: You should use `left_on` and `right_on` to specify the fields to join on.

Comment: Also, `all` isn't a valid argument for `merge`.  Do you mean to specify the join type, (e.g. `how='outer'`)?

Comment: @Chris thank you for your comment :) Could you please code it out so that I can understand what you mean? I am not too fluent with python, so I would appreciate something more visual!

Comment: Posted as an answer so I can format the code with comments in a more readable manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), the syntax for `pandas.merge` is:

```
merged_df = merge(
    fund_df,                     # left dataframe
    prices_df,                   # right dataframe
    left_on=['tic', 'year'],     # columns to join on in left dataframe
    right_on=['TICKER', 'year'], # columns to join on in right dataframe
    how='outer')                 # type of join (e.g. inner, outer, left, etc.)
```

Comment: That's great! It worked perfectly :) thank you @Chris!